# HTLM5 canvas game (easeljs) slow peformance on ipad (ios7) with phonegap

Tags: html, performance, ipad, cordova, easeljs

I have developed a game with easeljs for HTML5 Canvas.
the game is a single HTML5 page with canvas and a lot of javascript.

All this time I tested the app on iOS Safari (iPad3 iOS7) with 40~50 fps via a local server.
when I packed in a xcode app with phonegap, it becomes incredible slow near to 10fps..
I noticed the same behaviour when I added the page to homescreen.

There is any way to make make a good performance with html5 canvas app games for ipad (iOS7)?

Comment: I have no experience with this, but have been debating attempting a cordova/easeljs project.  Hope you get a good answer on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution for this.

The actual phonegap implementation uses default webViewer, which is quite slow. Ludei (www.ludei.com) has a great solution for HTML5 canvas high performance games, CocoonJS. It works great on iOS and Android, there is not for WindowsPhone. However there is no need for it on Windows Phone 8. Windows Phone 8 has the highest native HTML5 canvas performance I ever seen.

so Don't use Phonegap. Try CocoonJS!

Comment: Indeed this may be a useful solution for canvas games.  However, its useful to know exactly why:  CocoonJS bundles a javascript execution engine and provides a custom html5-canvas-like api that maps to a ios/android native drawing component.  You don't actually get web features like DOM, CSS, and is missing many JS apis.  To use those, Ludei uses a WebView based solution exactly like phonegap/cordova does, its just that they focus mostly on the former problem and cordova on the latter.  So, CocoonJS is a great solution for a certain problem, but isn't just universally better.

Comment: I Agree. The main purpose for it is the HTML5 Canvas. if you are using DOM, the default webview is fast enough. the default Canvas is quite bad, that is why using cocoonjs.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Phonegap. Try CocoonJS!

Comment: seems promissing, i will try